# Serving specific html file in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to setup a server with a static file route, a webservice api, and the home address at the root of the domain. My yesod app looks like this:

```
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/static StaticR Static getStatic
/ HomeR GET
... api routes
|]
```

Now I found how to serve static files and how to handle api requests. But I am stuck for the `getHomeR` definition. I would simply like to serve an `index.html` file. I could manually read it and pass it as a string. But is there an efficient built-in solution for serving a specific html file?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I found the answer 1 minute after asking (I had been searching for 20 minutes).

There is a nice helper in `Yesod.Handler` called `sendFile`. The `getHomeR` definition looks like this:

```
getHomeR :: Handler ()
getHomeR = do
    app <- getYesod
    let indexPath = getRootDir app </> "index.html"
    sendFile "text/html" indexPath
```

Comment: Do you know how to do when `index.html` calls some external files with `<script src=...>`? These files are not found at runtime.

Comment: You setup a directory containing all your static content (CSS, js, HTML, images etc). See https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Static-file-subsite-Hello-World.

Comment: Your server must respond to get requests of the form urltostatic/subpath with the file located at machinepathtostatic/subpath.

Comment: In my case, those paths look like www.mysite.com/static/whatever and the files served are located in c:/myapppath/static

Comment: I've managed [by this way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yesodweb/nOY6t6wWcRs).